# Postgres SUM over PARTITION BY "tolerate" null values

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a view which calculates rolling sum taking in value form previous row based on `PARTITION BY` clause, and I need to indicate one field in `PARTITION BY` clause can have nulls in them.

```
sum(s."QuantityChange") OVER (PARTITION BY s."LocationId", s."PartId", s."SupplierFacilityId" ORDER BY s."DueDate" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS "RunningSum"
```

Sometimes `SupplierFacilityId` is null and that's fine, it should still be included in the `sum()` calculation.

Is this possible with Postgres?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the issue?

Comment: How would NULL contribute to the sum?

Comment: You can have a partition where `s.LocationId` is `1`, `s.PartId` is `2` and  `s.SupplierFacilityId` is `NULL`. So where is the problem?

Comment: https://imgur.com/KtU2DrX this is showing what I have in mind. Running sum should be 445 on the last row.

Comment: Please edit and add this in the question, preferably as text, not image

Comment: So you want to have rows where `SupplierFacilityId` is null not as a separate partition but assign them to (possibly more than one) different partitions according to some rule. You'll have to specify what this rule would be.

Comment: Which grouping would you want it to be part of e.g values in `SupplierFacilityId` are `null, 1, 1, 2, 3` which of those values do you want to add its sum to? Or do you want a separate group for the null? From the screenshot you link above, it's unclear why `SupplierFacilityId` is being grouped at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4bWL.jpg) from the comment (which should be **text** in the **question**) shows that you run the query with this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE ... AND ("SupplierFacilityId" IS NULL OR "SupplierFacilityId" = 647)
```

So you can just drop `"SupplierFacilityId"` from `PARTITION BY` to achieve what you want: rows with `"SupplierFacilityId" IS NULL` are treated as equal peers of the partition:

```
sum(s."QuantityChange") OVER (PARTITION BY s."LocationId", s."PartId"
                              ORDER BY s."DueDate" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS "RunningSum"
```

Also, since the [default framing option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, and assuming that `(s."LocationId", s."PartId", s."DueDate")` is defined unique (which makes `RANGE` and `ROWS` equivalent in this context), you can just drop the custom framing options:

```
sum(s."QuantityChange") OVER (PARTITION BY s."LocationId", s."PartId"
                              ORDER BY s."DueDate") AS "RunningSum"
```

Without said `WHERE` clause, your goal would be unachievable with a simple window function as you would have to use the same rows with NULL values in multiple partitions. You would have to multiply those rows first ...

Comment: Perhaps they don't want to multiply the rows with null values but have a layer first where each null is assigned to a value (say with a rule to find the previous non-null value per `PARTITION BY s."LocationId", s."PartId" ORDER BY s."DueDate"`) and then do a rolling sum with `PARTITION BY s."LocationId", s."PartId", s."SupplierFacilityId"`.
Just another possibility, the OP has to clarify of course

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Yup, that's another way this might pan out. Or the query always has said `WHERE` condition anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As ypercube mentioned in the comments, it should still work even when the `SupplierFacilityId` is null. But if you're running into issues or want to force it to default to a specific value, you can use the `COALESCE()` function to replace the `NULL` value with something else.

---

Per your updated comments, here's an example query that uses a simple `CASE` statement to hopefully achieve the logic of your image:

```
CASE 
    WHEN s."SupplierFacilityId" IS NULL THEN s."QuantityChange" 
    ELSE sum(s."QuantityChange") OVER (PARTITION BY s."LocationId", s."PartId", s."SupplierFacilityId" ORDER BY s."DueDate" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
END AS "RunningSum"
```

Comment: this wont help me, I need the mechanism which calculates the sum on partition by column which are certain value OR they are null (to include them in the calculation)
imgur.com/KtU2DrX this is showing what I have in mind. Running sum should be 445 on the last row.

Comment: @vmachacek The only thing I was able to interpret from your image is that when the `SupplierFacilityId` is null then the `RunningSum` should be the `QuantityChange` (-20 in your image's example). I've updated my code to reflect this with a simple `CASE` statement. If you need the rules to be different than that, then please specify the exact rules you want it to follow.